# C# function that accepts a jagged array of any dimension

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, visual-studio

Is there anyway to declare a function that takes in a jagged array of any dimension in C#? Right now if I pass in a jagged array in a function that takes in 1 dimensional arrays it would give me an error:

```
void func<T>(T[] arr){ 
  return; 
}

double[][] x = new double[10][];
func<double>(x);
// Error: cannot convert from double[][] to double[]
```

Is there any way I can change the function signature to make it accept both 1 dimensional array and jagged arrays? The function will only perform actions that would work on both jagged arrays and 1D arrays. I don't really want to use overload since the dimension of the jagged array might be unknown.

Comment: You don't need to change the function signature. You are calling the function wrongly. Try calling it like this: `func(x)` or `func<double[]>(x)`.

Comment: Can you not just convert the one-dimensional array to a jagged array? int[][] jaggedArray = { oneDimArray };

Comment: you can pass in an array object: `void func<T>(Array arr)` Since Array object can represent any array type and any dimensions. Doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @Sweeper or let the compiler determine the correct type and just write `func(x)`

Answer (score 3):

To accept an array argument of any type, any size, and any number of dimensions, you can use the `Array` class from the `System` namespace.

Here is what it would look like:

```
void Function(Array arr)
{
    //Do your stuff with "arr", 
    //you can mostly just treat it like a normal array, looping and so on...
}
```

And if you would like to know the length of a specific dimension, just use the `Array.GetLength(int Dimension)` function.

If you would also like to know how many dimensions this array has, just use the Array.Rank property.

As for the question, you can simply do this and it wont cause any problems:

```
double[][] x = new double[10][];
Func<double>(x);
```

---

MS Doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netcore-3.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.rank?view=netcore-3.1

Hope this helped you!

Comment: As for the question, you can simply do this and it wont cause any problems: 
`double[][] x = new double[10][];
Func<double>(x);`

Comment: I would suggest adding that comment into the answer itself, as it may be the most useful aspect for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to declare a function that takes in a jagged array of any dimension in C#?

Yes, and you already actually have one. Your solution takes any `T[]`, and `T` itself can be an array type - which is precisely how jagged arrays work. So let's take your original function (and just change the name to be more conventional and avoid confusion with the `Func` delegate type):

```cs
void ProcessArray<T>(T[] array)
{ 
    // (Method body is irrelevant for now)
}
```

If you want that method to process a `double[]`, then the *type argument* for the method (i.e. the type of `T` for that method invocation) needs to be `double`. If you want the method to process a `double[][]`, the type argument needs to be `double[]`, and so on.

You can do this by explicitly specifying the type argument:

```cs
double[] simpleArray = new double[10];
ProcessArray<double>(simpleArray);

double[][] jaggedArray = new double[10][];
ProcessArray<double[]>(jaggedArray);
```

Alternatively, you can use *generic type inference* to let the compiler figure out what type argument you want for `T` automatically:

```cs
double[] simpleArray = new double[10];
ProcessArray(simpleArray);

double[][] jaggedArray = new double[10][];
ProcessArray(jaggedArray);
```

In my experience, you can *usually* use type inference when calling generic methods, but there are exceptions where you need to specify the type arguments explicitly.

The problem you faced was that you were providing a type argument of `double`, but a regular argument of type `double[][]`.

Now, if in your method you want to process all the individual elements, e.g. recursively calling your method with each of the "less jagged" arrays, you may need to use either reflection (e.g. `typeof(T).GetElementType()`) or members of the [`Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netcore-3.1) type to get more information at execution time. We don't know what your method needs to accomplish, so we can't provide any more concrete advice than that right now - but hopefully you can experiment with those two approaches.

Answer (score -1):

`<T>` means any type. As long as you respect the operations and the valid states of this mystical type `<T>` it can be anything. Furthermore,  is deduced from the types you feed the method as its parameters, so you need only to be explicit when *declaring it* but not when *invoking* it.

So, you made a change to accept N-dimensional arrays called... idk, Transform:

This could be its signature: `void Transform<T>(T array)`. In this case T is already an array, if the parameter was an array of type T (example: `void f<T>(T[] a`) this would be the signature, and so on.

T is a template, a type potentially built when you compile (and sometimes even at runtime). The power of template programming immense, and due to C#'s *coder first* philosophy we get to experience in its full glory without having to shed several tears over a C++ text-book.

Comment: This shows how to create a method accepting *any* type, which isn't the same as a method accepting *only an array*. Tommy's answer is the one that actually solves the OP's problem, I believe. (Although so does the OP's original code, if they're happy with not being able to accept multi-dimensional arrays.)

Comment: "T is a template" - no, it's a generic type parameter. It's best not to start confusing C++ template terminology with C# generics terminology.

Comment: OP's problem is simpler than he thinks. The methods are still created at compile (or run) time, and whenever you call f<t>(T a, T b), you generate a method for the corresponding sig. (T being replaced by any type, array or not). I just tried to show the OP the fact that **T** stands for **anything...** I didn't answer his question precisely, which was wrong, but I tried to add to his overall knowledge of the language and programming in general.

Comment: Well despite knowing C# well, I didn't really understand what you were trying to say, so I suspect it hasn't been of help to the OP either. I certainly don't want to discourage you from trying to help - I just think you missed the mark this time (and the reference to templates definitely doesn't help).

Comment: <T> is the *GENERIC* type of the method. If you have ``F<T>(T[] a)`` then if ``T`` is ``double[]``, parameter ``T[] a`` means ``T = double[],`` and ``T[] = double[][]``. That's what I meant. Maybe if people had let the OP read my answer first before mangling it for not being *academic* enough to present as master's thesis, he could understand, just maybe, have understood it better than his tutorials, teachs, and books have been trying to teach him so far. All I wanted to do was to show the OP that there is nothing special about a method with a type parameter.

Comment: Yes, I'm very well aware of generics - and that they're not the same as C++ templates. I don't think anyone has said that your answer ought to be more "academic" - I've said I think it's unclear, and doesn't really answer the question. (It's also not generally true that you only need to be explicit when declaring a generic method - *sometimes* the C# compiler can infer the types based on the arguments, but there are plenty of times when you *do* need to explicitly specify the type arguments.) Maybe it's time to add my own answer here...